# How to efficiently select element in a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

How can I write an efficient version of the following statement?

```
Cases[list, {_, feature_} /; feature < constant]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

List is of the form, list = {{feature11,feature12},...,{featuren1,featuren2}}. It has a length in the order of 10^5. On my laptop, a Macbook pro from last year it takes around 0.25s. However, I need to evaluate this expression a lot of times. Any suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {500000, 2}];
constant = 0.3;
(ans1 = Cases[data, {_, feature_} /; feature < constant]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.880057, Null}

```
(ans2 = Select[data, Last@# < constant &]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.219078, Null}

```
(ans3 = Pick[data, Round[Last@# + (0.5 - constant)] & /@ data, 0]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.110006, Null}

```
(ans4 = Pick[data, Round[data[[All, 2]] + (0.5 - constant)], 0]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.045003, Null}

```
ans1 == ans2 == ans3 == ans4
```

> True

Comment: For those data which have a larger range than {0,1}, using Round[(constant - data[[All, 2]])/10^n - .5] instead of Round[data[[All, 2]] + (0.5 - constant)] may be helpful. n can be any number to assure that Abs[(constant - data[[All, 2]])/10^n] < 0.5.

Comment: `Pick[data, Sign[data[[All, 2]] - constant], -1]`