# Using Select function to select elements based on last element of nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Good morning,

I have a list with each element containing a tuple and a single. It is of this form:

```
{{{{2015,5,13},{2015,8,31}},100}, {{{2010,2,3},{2010,2,17}},14},......}
```

I am trying to select elements that have the last element equal to 100. I want the output to be the entire element, so in this example I want `{{{2015,5,13},{2015,8,21}},100}` to be output.

My list is called `dbp`, and the select function I have been trying is:

```
Select[dbp, dbp[[#]][[2]] == 100 & /@ Range[Length[dbp]]]
```

This always returns an empty set.

I know my calling of that element is correct, because:

```
dbp[[12]][[2]]
```

displays the proper element. I also know that the element is findable because:

```
(dbp[[#]][[2]] == 100) & /@ Range[Length[dbp]]
```

yields `True` for the element I am looking for. What I can't figure out is why this doesn't work in the Select function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Select[dbp, Last[#] == 100 &]`? Or, `Cases[dbp, {m_?MatrixQ, 100}]`...

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58782/how-to-efficiently-select-element-in-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a wrong syntax for `Select`

```
data = {{{{2015, 5, 13}, {2015, 8, 31}}, 100}, {{{2010, 2, 3}, {2010, 2, 17}},
     14}, {{{2013, 5, 13}, {2013, 8, 31}}, 
    100}, {{{2010, 2, 3}, {2010, 2, 17}}, 
    14}, {{{2011, 5, 13}, {2011, 8, 31}}, 
    100}, {{{2010, 2, 3}, {2010, 2, 17}}, 14}};

Select[data, #[[-1]] == 100 &]
```

> {{{{2015, 5, 13}, {2015, 8, 31}}, 100}, {{{2013, 5, 13}, {2013, 8,
>   31}},    100}, {{{2011, 5, 13}, {2011, 8, 31}}, 100}}

```
Select[data, #[[2]] == 100 &]
```

> {{{{2015, 5, 13}, {2015, 8, 31}}, 100}, {{{2013, 5, 13}, {2013, 8,
>   31}},    100}, {{{2011, 5, 13}, {2011, 8, 31}}, 100}}